# RX programming - how to get previous messages from MessageBroker?

Tags: rxjs, unirx

I use UniRX (C#) which tries to resemble RXJS and others.

I try to make sure my network-dependent objects initialize *after* the data arrived.

Some of my objects get created and Subscribe *later* than MSGPlayerDataLoaded actually fired thus never proceed to OnPlayerDataLoaded.

```
    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        MessageBroker.Default.Receive<BaseMessage>().Where(msg => msg.id == GameController.MSGPlayerDataLoaded).Subscribe(msg => OnPlayerDataLoaded());
    }
```

Is it possible to look into the past and grab old events since creation of MessageBroker?

From the documentation of RXJS I suspect that something like withLatestFrom could be of help, but it would need a dummy auxiliary stream that looks hacky.

Comment: If I understand right your question in the rxjs world you should look at `shareReplay` operator

Comment: @Picci I think you're right! I found Replay operator, but can't get how to apply to MessageBroker. Just chaining it with Subscribe does not work.